# Clear an automatic Setinterval to open a modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-modal, setinterval

I have a list update part in my php where the ajax will update the list. The list is generated through sql queries and in a while loop. So it creates n number of list based on database values. Now I have a button on every list which will open up a modal box.

The update is done through set interval function below

```js
var int = startinterval();

function startinterval() {
  interval = setInterval(fetch_list, 1000);
  return interval;
}

function fetch_list() {
  var action = "fetch_data";
  $.ajax({
    url: "list.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      action: action
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('.list').html(data);
    }
  })
}
```

My Html where the data is updated to the list class

```
<div class="col-lg-12 list" style="overflow-y: auto;height: 400px;">
```

Now my problem is when i click the button on the list (as mention earlier) which should normally open up the modal box. Due to setInterval constantly updating the list every sec, the modal when open dissapears and goes hidden.

So what I'm trying is when I click the button to open the modal, it should stop the setinterval function. The setinterval should come back running once I click the cancel button inside the modal.

I tried many ways to clearinterval(), but no success. So expecting someone's help for me to get the wheels rolling.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**
my list would look like the below screenshot.
[image: sample list]

My list.php

```
if($_POST["action"] == "fetch_data")
{
    echo fetch_list($connect);
}


function fetch_list($connect)
{
    if(!$_SESSION['id']){
        $output = '<ul class="list-unstyled"><h4>Please Select a Programme</h4></ul>';
        return $output;
    }else{
    $query = "
    SELECT * FROM list_programme
    WHERE pid = '".$_SESSION['id']."' 
    ORDER BY pid ASC
    ";

    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);

    $statement->execute();

    $result = $statement->fetchAll();

    $output = '<ul class="list-unstyled">';
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        if($row["user"] == $_SESSION["uid"])
        {

            if($row["pstatus"] == '2')
            {
                $tickstatus = 'color:white';
                $pcontrol = 'bg-success';
                $pname = $row["pname"];
                $border =   'border-color:#999;';
                $pid        = $row['pid'];
                $notification = 'incomplete';
            }
            else
            {
                $pname = $row["pname"];
                $pid        = $row['pid'];
                $notification = 'complete';
            }
        }
        else
        {

        }

        $output .= '

    <div class="x_panel">
                    <button class="btn btn-round button-pcontrol '.$pcontrol.'" id="'.$pid.'" value="'.mb_strimwidth($pname, 0, 21, "...").'" data-notification="'.$notification.'" onClick="markcheck(this.id,this.value,this.dataset.notification)" style="'.$border.'"><i class="material-icons" title="Mark Completed" style="'.$tickstatus.'">check</i></button><span class="pname">'.$pname.'</span>
                    <span class="pcontrolbuttons">
                        <button class="btn btn-round button-pcontrol" id="programme" onClick="stopinterval()" data-id="'.$pid.'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#programme'.$pid.'"><i class="material-icons" title="Assign users">person_add</i></button>
                        <button class="btn btn-round button-taskcontrol" data-id="'.$pid.'" data-value="'.mb_strimwidth($pname, 0, 21, "...").'" onClick="deleteprgm(this.dataset.id,this.dataset.value)"><i class="material-icons" title="Delete Task">delete</i></button>
                    </span>
                </div>

                <!--Modal -->
                <div id="programme'.$id.'" class="modal custom-modal fade" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title text-center">Add to this programme</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                Some Input elements, Drop downs, etc.,
                                </div>

                                <div class="submit-section">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success submit-btn" id="addnusers"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add Users</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary submit-btn" id="closeassignee" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Close</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /Modal -->';

    }
    $output .= '</ul>';
    return $output;
}
}
```

Comment: Starting an interval and making an AJAX request within it is not the cause of your modal being closed immediately. There must be some other code doing that. If you are trying to clear the interval then just `clearInterval(int)` will work, so long as `int` is in scope. That being said, making an AJAX request in an interval will most likely cause server performance problems, so it's not a good idea.

Comment: Sorry, I have a button that comes along with the ajax success result. That button when clicked opens the modal. When modal is opened it dissapears immediately after 1 sec. I believe it is because of setinterval

Comment: There's nothing in the code which will close a modal. The only thing I can think is that clicking the button perhaps submits a parent `form` element and causes the page to reload/redirect

Comment: Modal is not closed, it just dissapears. What would be the best way that you can suggest apart from setinterval to update the list without page refresh

Comment: Is the `button` you add to the DOM contained within a `form`?

Comment: Its not a form actually. Its like a table data with buttons

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207292/discussion-between-theveil-and-rory-mccrossan).

Comment: Could you please include the modal code?

Comment: In which HTML element is the class `list` you're calling here `$('.list').html(data);`?

Comment: Does `<div class="col-lg-12 list" style="overflow-y: auto;height: 400px;">` wraps the whole content? Please, provide complete information so that we can help you out.

Comment: Yes the list class wraps the whole content

Comment: I strongly believe this is error caused by setInterval. When i change it to setTimeout, this doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for many resources, I had no luck to fix my issues with SetInterval.

So instead I modified my code to use setTimeout function. And the main drawback is this will not do live updates but once some button are clicked to modify the contents, the ajax success will call the setTimeout function and my list will be updated. So for time being the purpose is served.

Thanks for all the response.

Below is the single piece of code I Modified instead of a setInterval function

```
setTimeout(fetch_list, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

> So what I'm trying is when I click the button to open the modal, it
>   should stop the setinterval function.

You always should stops the functions execution, otherwise it will call the AJAX once per second and change the content of the modal.

```
document.getElementById('#button').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    clearInterval(int);
    // open modal
});
```

> The setinterval should come back running once I click the cancel
>   button inside the modal.

```
document.getElementById('#cancel').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    startinterval();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But still modal goes hidden.

Comment: Could you please post the whole code that renders this page or maybe the piece that renders `$('.list')`?